# NOTEPAD ++ List: How to put each word on new line

Tags: list, notepad++

If this cane be done with notepad++ I'm sure it's something simple I'm looking over. Or if there is another way i'm all ears.

I have a list of 10,000 - 20,000 words. Each word is a single word. No spaces in any one word but a single space between each and every word.

All the words are in a straight line format and rap-around. I would like to put each word on a new line all the way down my txt file. I need this as I need to be able to append something on the front and back of each word. That I can do. But I do not have the the 24 hours its going to take to drop each word manually. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This is a question about notepad++ not about programming. You might try a Notepad++ maillist or website.

Comment: Well I am programming. It's directly related the the application I am designing. But thinking of it that way I guess the issue itself is rather off topic of programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the Replace function search for space and replace with \n remember to use the extended option.

Comment: I seriously love you right now. It worked. Just saved me a day or two of work in about 3 seconds. =)

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the extended version but it didn't work for me so I tried with regular expression it works for me. Here is step by step process:

- First type ctrl + H on windows. (Find & Replace)
- In find section type: [ ]+              **(there is single space between the brackets)**
- In the replace section type: \n
- Select the Regular Expression option.
- Finally, click on find & replace all.

It will automatically put all words in the new line.

Hope it will work for you as well!